# Batch script for moving files to correct folder

Tags: file, batch-file, move, directory-structure

I am looking for help to construct a .bat script to move PDFs into a predefined folder structure. The file names are structured and relate to where in the folder structure they should be moved to.

For example **IRTYCAS001.pdf**;

- First two letters tell it to move it to the correct country folder (Ireland)
- 3rd and 4th will tell it what county folder to move it to
- 5th to 7th will tell it the correct town folder to move it to and
- Last 3 digits tell it the land use type folder to move it to

The identifier lengths will always be the same in the file name.

The folder structure looks something like
[example of folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9OpL.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With extensions enabled (default) [mkdir](http://ss64.com/nt/mkdir.html) will create intermediate folders in one step.
So all  you've to do is

- iterate the files
- use substrings to split the filename into parts and
- create the folders if not already existing.

---

```
@echo off & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set Src=A:\
set Dst=A:\
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('Dir /B "%Src%*.pdf"') do (
    Set "File=%%A"
    set "Folder=%Dst%\!File:~0,2!\!File:~2,2!\!File:~4,3!\!File:~7,3!\"
    if not exist "!Folder!" MD "!Folder!" >NUL
    Move "%%A" "!Folder!"
)
```

Sample tree:

```
> tree . /f
A:\
└───IR
    └───TY
        └───CAS
            └───001
                    IRTYCAS001.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like this:

```
FOR /F %%i IN ('dir /b c:\temp\*.pdf') DO call :moveFiles %%i

goto :EOF

:moveFiles
set myfile=%1
set part1=%myfile:~0,2%
set part2=%myfile:~2,2%
set part3=%myfile:~4,3%
set part4=%myfile:~7,3%

set dstFolder=C:\temp

if %part1%==IR set dstFolder=%dstFolder%\ireland
REM more options here...

if %part2%==TY set dstFolder=%dstFolder%\tipperary
REM more options here...

if %part3%==CAS set dstFolder=%dstFolder%\cashel
REM more options here...

if %part4%==001 set dstFolder=%dstFolder%\residential
REM more options here...


move /Y %myfile% %dstFolder%
```